# symfony admin generator foreign key listing

Tags: symfony-1.4, admin-generator

Hi I am using symfony 1.4 doctrine orm. I have three tables for example course, calendar and course_offering. Course_offering table has two foreign keys to course and calendar table. In admin generator, the course_offering_module just retrieve these two ID's. Instead I want values seperated by commas, also If I add new course offering it should automatically modify that foreign key tables too. This can be possible in admin generator? how?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add __toString() method tou your models, to return the value you want instead of ids.

```
// lib/model/doctrine/JobeetJob.class.php
class JobeetJob extends BaseJobeetJob
{
  public function __toString()
  {
    return sprintf('%s at %s (%s)', $this->getPosition(), $this->getCompany(), $this->getLocation());
  }
}
```

Second, if you want render a specific layout, you can use partial as column in admingen:

```
# apps/backend/modules/job/config/generator.yml
config:
  form:
    display:
      Content: [category_id, type, company, logo, url, position, location, description, how_to_apply, is_public, email]
      Admin:   [_generated_token, is_activated, expires_at]


// apps/backend/modules/job/templates/_generated_token.php
<div class="sf_admin_form_row">
  <label>Token</label>
  <?php echo $form->getObject()->getToken() ?>
</div>
```